# custom template rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a page called `my-todo-list` and is using a custom page template.

The page is accessible via this type of URL : `http://domain.com/my-todo-list/`

Now I need to paginate it, and I want to look like this: `http://domain.com/my-todo-list/page/1`

I've read a lot of questions here, but nothing clear.

Any Ideas to make it possible? my template needs something like`$page= $_GET['page']` ?

Comment: You'll actually want to use [`get_query_var( 'paged' )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var), not `$_GET[]`, as there are no parameters in the URL, since it has been rewritten.

Comment: Outstanding, I submitted it as an answer so you can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you will want to use is [`get_query_var( 'paged' )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var). This will get the default pagination value, this should be set by default, so you should just be able to plug and play. Because there are no URL parameters due to rewriting, `$_GET[]` will be completely empty (at least on the example URLs).